# get_post_meta isn't printing/exposing assigned custom fields in Wordpress functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I have no idea why this isn't working. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php
add_shortcode( 'CuFi' , 'CuFi_shortcode_callback');
    function CuFi_shortcode_callback() {
    $Title = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'book', true);
    $Number = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'isbn', true);
    if (!empty ( $Title )) {
       echo '<p> Book Title: ' . $Title . '</p>';
       echo '<p>ISBN: ' . $Number . '</p>';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: What do you exactly mean with "non working"? By just watching i can smell issues since you are using the $post variable w/o defining it. At least you are missing "global $post;" and then we need to know where you are trying to use that shortcode. The global $post var may not exist at that time

Comment: Please edit your question to include a proper explanation of what "not working" actually means in your case. What happens? https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just put global $post in your code

beacuse you did't get post ID

```
add_shortcode( 'CuFi' , 'CuFi_shortcode_callback');
    function CuFi_shortcode_callback() {
    global $post;
    $Title = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'book', true);
    $Number = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'isbn', true);
    if (!empty ( $Title )) {
       echo '<p> Book Title: ' . $Title . '</p>';
       echo '<p>ISBN: ' . $Number . '</p>';
    }
}
```

i hope it works fine in your site : ) cheers

Comment: Thank you Mehul Poraniya for your help. It "works" as desired now. Cheers!

Comment: @mgk could you please set my answer as the accepted if it helped. :)